# Can't find the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 in my loop

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I tried to solve the celebrity problem. You got a 2d array filled with 0 and 1. The row (=person) which only contains 1, is the celebrity. 
The int n is 0 if there's none, and will be the columns number of the 2d array where a row only contains 1.

The problem is, that I can't find the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. It has to be anywhere in the loop. I used a 5x5 2d array and started with `i = 0`.
The loop only works until `i : 3`  and then throws the exception.

```
public int startSearch(int[][] matrix , int i) {
    int j = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int esc = 0;

    while(esc == 0) {
        if(matrix[i][j] == 1) {
            j++;

            if( j >= (matrix.length +1) ) {
                n = i+1;
                esc = 1;
            }
        }

        if(matrix[i][j] == 0) {
            esc = 1;
        }
    }

    i++;
    if( i <= matrix.length) {
        System.out.println("i : " +i);
        System.out.println(n);
        startSearch(matrix, i);
    }
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Maybe `if( i <= matrix.length){`should be `if( i < matrix.length){    `

Comment: Run it in the debugger. THat is what they are for

Comment: already tried that one, still the same error. Thanks for your reply, though!
Also debugged it, but got no clue how to change it.

Comment: can to add the stacktrace of error please

Comment: Post a [MCVE] in order to get help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to note that in **Java** the arrays will have indices *from 0 to length-1* so `0, 1, 2, 3, 4` for your array of size 5.

In your loop you are checking :

```
if( j >= (matrix.length +1) ) {
    n = i+1;
    esc = 1;
}

// and 

if( i <= matrix.length){    
    System.out.println("i : " +i);
    System.out.println(n);
    startSearch(matrix, i);
}
```

You should be checking:

```
if( j >= matrix.length ) {
    n = i+1;
    esc = 1;
}

// and 

if( i < matrix.length){    
    System.out.println("i : " +i);
    System.out.println(n);
    startSearch(matrix, i);
}
```

Otherwise for example in your case for `i = 3` you might have `j = 5` as `5 < 5+1`

Answer (score 0):

Put a check before this line `if(matrix[i][j] == 1)`

```
if(i<matrix.length && j<matrix[i].length)
{
if(matrix[i][j] == 1)
{
//rest all same
```

Also put a check before this line `if(matrix[i][j] == 0){`

```
if(i<matrix.length && j<matrix[i].length)
{
if(matrix[i][j] == 0){
//rest all same
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably be this line: `if(j >= (matrix.length + 1)){`

Where the j will enter this if loop when j == matrix.length + 1 and before this,  visiting `matrix[i][matrix.length]` will cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, because the index of an array with length n is between [0, n - 1], and it is for sure that there will be an error when you try to get the value of index n.